# Converting csv to json adds '\r' characters

Tags: javascript, line-endings

I have a method that converts csv to json data:

Here is the code:

```
    CSV2JSON(): void {
      const lines = this.csvData.split('\n');
      const result = [];
      const headers = lines[0].split(',');
      console.log(headers);
      for (let i = 1; i < lines.length - 1; i++ ) {
       const obj = {};
       const currentline = lines[i].split(',');

       for (let j = 0; j < headers.length; j++) {
        obj[headers[j]] = currentline[j];
       }

      result.push(obj);

   }

    console.log(JSON.stringify(result)); // JSON
}
```

This is giving me:

```
[{"name":"test1","code z\r":"0.030\r"}]
```

As you can see there's `'\r'` which shouldn't be there.

How can I get rid of those `\r` or stop them appearing in the json data?

Comment: This isn't Angular-related. If your original string had \n\r for line endings, spitting at \n would give you \r on the right side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is with line-endings, not Angular. Different operating systems have different standards on how to encode the "new line" character; this is a common annoying issue when parsing human-readable strings (such as the CSV format). You read about this in detail [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline), for example.

The `\r` you're getting probably means that the original file had `\n\r` for line endings. When you do a split at `\n`, the right-hand part will retain the leading `\r`. To remove the `\r` as well, you'll have to split by `\n\r` instead, treating the whole group as a new line.

```js
const s = `foo\n\rbar`
console.log(s.split('\n'))    // bad
console.log(s.split('\n\r'))  // good
```

But if you do this blindly, you're going to miss the cases when a new line *is* simply `\n`.

```js
const s = `foo\nbar`
console.log(s.split('\n'))    // good
console.log(s.split('\n\r'))  // bad
```

To handle both, you could firstly replace all instance of `\n\r` with just `\n`, and then split.

```js
const s = `foo\n\rbar\nbaz`
console.log(s.replace(/\n\r/g, '\n').split('\n'))
```

However, with this code, you're going to miss other operating systems which use only `\r` for the new line. You can either handle this case as well, or use an existing library for parsing CSV. There's probably a few to choose from on the NPM repository.

Comment: nice and elaborate answer!. For those \r cases you can chain one last substitution: `console.log(s.replace(/\n\r/g, '\n').replace('\n','\r').split('\r'))`

Comment: \r 's are still there ... I'm updated the original code as it was missing the last line. Hope you can help

Comment: @yea2021 Have you tried `const lines = this.csvData.replace(/\n\r/g, '\n').replace('\n','\r').split('\r');` ?